# ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I created a dockerfile in order to create an image for my script `checkDNS.py` using **zabbix_sender** to send infos to **Zabbix***.

Follow my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.9.5-slim

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y dnsutils \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY /opt/git/files/zabbix-sender.deb /tmp/
```

I moved my `zabbix-sender.deb` to `/opt/git/files/zabbix-sender.deb`.

When I execute the command `docker build -f /opt/git/df/Dockerfile-zabbix-checkDNS -t image-zabbix-checkdns:1.0 .` I get the below error:

```
ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat opt/git/files/zabbix-sender.deb: file does not exist .
```

Can someone help me please to solve this issue?

Thank you in advance